# Azure logic app with AS2 connector through VPN

Tags: azure, vpn, azure-logic-apps, azure-vpn

I am currently setting up an Azure logic app with an AS2 connector.

Now I am being asked to connect to the partner via VPN. From googling I think that is possible to somehow add the logic app to a VNET and then setup a site-to-site VPN gateway.

It is my first time to work with either Logic apps or AS2.

**Question:**

1. Is it possible to setup an Azure logic app with AS2 connector that connects through a VPN?
2. How might I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

First of all, you need to [connect to Azure virtual networks from Azure Logic Apps by using an integration service environment (ISE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/connect-virtual-network-vnet-isolated-environment), With ISE, you deploy the Logic Apps service into your virtual network.

When you create a logic app or integration account, select your ISE as their location. Your logic app or integration account can then directly access resources, such as virtual machines (VMs), servers, systems, and services, in your virtual network. This virtual network can be an existing VNet that has a VPN connection to the partner or you can select an Azure VNet as a [peer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview) for your environment.

You may note those [prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/connect-virtual-network-vnet-isolated-environment#prerequisites) before your deploy ISE, and your ISE needs four **empty** subnets that aren't delegated to any service. You also can optionally set up NSGs by [filtering network traffic across subnets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-filter-network-traffic).

Here is a detailed explanation in this blog--[Introducing Azure Logic Apps Integration Service Environment (ISE).](https://dzone.com/articles/introducing-azure-logic-apps-integration-service-e)

For more references: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/connect-virtual-network-vnet-isolated-environment-overview